# what does backgrounding a process in Kali Linux really do?

Tags: background-process

### Context

---

I have checked several questions about the same topic and I still get confused when they explain what a background process really is. The common answer I interpert is that:

> a process that runs in the background allows you to interact with the same terminal... etc.

I have tested this by running the following command:

- `ping google.com -c 100 &`
- P.S: I also ran this same command without the `&` operator and used Ctrl-Z, but all that did was suspend the command

### Question

---

When I ran this command, the output was still in my main terminal, and I could not execute any other commands until the command was finished running, or until I killed the command.

**Before I list my questions, my questions is not how to redirect the output of a command to a seperate file / place**.  I am already aware of how to redirect the output of `ping google.com -c 100` command to a different place so I can still interact with the main terminal

My questions are

- In the most simplest terms possible, what does backgrounding a command actually do
- What does putting a `&` at the end of a command do
- What is the purpose of doing this / what do I gain out of backgrounding a command
- When would I want to background a command

** *Please let me know if you need further clarification about the quesitons or the context*

Comment: If you have this level of experience you really should not be trying to learn using Kali Linux. It's a specialist distribution for security professionals who are familiar not only with their trade but also with Linux in general. I would _strongly_ recommend you start with a more friendly distribution such as Mint or Ubuntu

Comment: I appreciate your input but with all due respect, if you do not wish to answer my question, please refrain from commenting. It is simply a waste of both of our time. I am aware that Kali Linux is an advanced debian-based distro of Linux, and I am aware it will be hard to learn. If I struggle, I struggle. Please answer my question or move on. Have a Great Evening

Comment: This is more a question about shell job / process management in general than Kali Linux specifically.  That it's Kali is irrelevant.

Comment: You totally can run other commands while `ping` is running in the background, it's just really confusing because `ping`'s output gets mixed in with everything else -- the shell prompt, what you type in as a command, what that command outputs, etc. So backgrounding is most useful (/least confusing) for things that don't constantly spit output the way `ping` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering these in the context of an interactive shell.  The behaviors are subtly different but largely similar within the context of a shell script.

- In the most simplest terms possible, what does backgrounding a command actually do

Backgrounding a command (or other process) allows it to execute while still allowing you to interact with the shell (i. e. start *new* processes).

- What does putting a & at the end of a command do

The `&` delimiter signifies the end of a given command and immediately drops the process invoked by that command to background execution.  It is analogous so the `;` delimiter which signifies the end of a given command to be executed until it terminates, whereupon a new shell prompt is provided.

- What is the purpose of doing this / what do I gain out of backgrounding a command
- When would I want to background a command

These are essentially the same question.  The short answer is:  When you are about to execute a command which will take a long time to run, but you can continue to do other things while executing it.  One example would be, for a contrived for-instance:

```
$ tail -f /path/to/apache-log > ~/webserverlog.txt &
$ curl --silent -o /dev/null https://localhost/path/site/you/are/debugging
$ kill %1
```

Comment: Thank your for clarifying this.

Comment: I would add: for simple cases, to background a non-background process after the fact, CTRL-Z followed by the `bg` builtin command (meaning background) often does the job.